# Кроссбраузерность события wheel

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть следующий код для плавной прокрутки до нужного места (до блока с индексами соответственно blockID и blockID2). Прокрутка срабатывает при движении колесика мыши. Код работает в FIREFOX, но не работает в яндексе и гугле. Почему?

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event){
    const blockID = "#block2";
    const blockID2 = "#block_sum";
    if(event.deltaY>0){
        document.querySelector('' + blockID).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start"
        });
    }
    if(event.deltaY<0){
        document.querySelector('' + blockID2).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "end"
        });
    }
});
```